# How do I merge Kotlin and Swift apps in new React Native app and keep the signing

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, kotlin, mobile

I have 2 apps that are the same, only 1 is for Android (built in Kotlin) and the other for iOS (built using SwiftUI).
They're live and being used by about 1500 people at the moment.

Now I've rebuilt the app using React Native. Hoping for a single code base to manage both Android and iOS apps. So far so good, but now i want to release the React Native apps, as updates for the current apps. This is where it gets tricky. I can find tutorials about how to integrate React Native in an existing Android or iOS app, but nothing about how to "merge" an Android and an iOS app in a new React Native app, and still be able to sign them as "updates" for the existing apps.

Hoping someone can shed some light on what needs to be done in order for this to work.

Comment: There is no “merge”. Upload an app to the App Store with the same bundle ID and it will be an update.

Comment: There is no merging, test test test. Once you upload the new react app with the old bundle ID users will get the new version. But like I mentioned test test test. There are an infinite number of things that could go wrong, install your store app onto a device and then install the react app, check everything….

Comment: That's seriously it? Just make sure the bundle ID is the same and youre good to go?

Comment: As you seem surprised that all you have to do is ensure the bundle id is the same, it seems like there's something on your mind you think is necessary that you haven't articulated. So perhaps you could explain what you mean by merge, what you think a merge might do or need to do from your perspective.

Comment: @Gruntcakes thanks for the question. I have the current live app on my android phone (built in Kotlin), when i hook it up to the laptop, and install the new React Native app, with the same bundle ID, i get an error saying:
`INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Existing package <package_name> signatures do not match newer version; ignoring!`

Which suggests that the signing might cause an issue

Comment: @Remi I'm an iOS expert so unfortunately can't comment on the Android aspect, but you should be ok with iOS with what you are doing